# Trying to loop over colums in DataFrame and strip Dollar Sign

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame has way too many columns to manully type in all of the columns separately. Therefore I am trying to loop through them quickly and get rid of the dollar signs and the commas in the large numbers. This is the code that I have so far:

```
for column in df1:
    df1[column] = df1[column].str.lstrip('$')
```

and I am getting the error:

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter just the str columns using [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
for col in df.select_dtypes([np.object]):
    df[col] = df[col].str.lstrip('$')
```

Example:

```
In [309]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'int':np.arange(3), 'float':[0.1,2.3,4.0], 'str':['$d', 'a$', 'asd']})
df

Out[309]:
   float  int  str
0    0.1    0   $d
1    2.3    1   a$
2    4.0    2  asd

In [310]:
for col in df.select_dtypes([np.object]):
    df[col] = df[col].str.lstrip('$')
df

Out[310]:
   float  int  str
0    0.1    0    d
1    2.3    1   a$
2    4.0    2  asd
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, would I use the same method for removing commas in the thousands place only with .strip?

Comment: If you loaded the data using `read_csv` it has a `thousands` arg: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv so you can do `df = pd.read_csv(file, thousands=',')` otherwise yes you can do what you suggest but you'd need to cast the column so `df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',','').astype(int)`